# Recyclerview view implementation using MVVM architecture

Tags: android

I want to implement recyclerview in Android kotlin using MVVM ARCHITECTURE which includes data binding, view model, repository, live data etc. I don't know how I can implement this. Please some one guide me. it would be very helpful if they write code, because I know all these clean architecture components but don't know how to make them work together.

I can implement recyclerview without MVVM architecture but I want to do it MVVM way.andr

Answer (score 1):

#### Step 1: Set up your project

Ensure you have a Kotlin-based Android project created. In your `build.gradle` (Module: app) file, make sure to include the necessary dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"

    // Data Binding
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }

    // RecyclerView
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
}
```

#### Step 2: Create your ViewModel

Use Flow and SharedFlow for data management in your ViewModel:

```kotlin
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow

class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _itemList = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
    val itemList = _itemList.asStateFlow()

    // Simulate loading data from a repository using Flow
    fun loadItems() {
        // Replace with your data loading logic
        val data = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
        _itemList.value = data
    }
}
```

#### Step 3: Create your Repository

Create a Repository class to fetch data from various sources (e.g., a network API, a local database). In this example, we'll simulate data retrieval.

```kotlin
class MyRepository {
    // Replace with your actual data source or API calls
    fun fetchData(): List<String> {
        return listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3")
    }
}
```

#### Step 4: Create your RecyclerView Adapter

Create an Adapter class for your RecyclerView. This class binds data to the RecyclerView items.

```kotlin
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.databinding.databinding.ItemLayoutBinding

class MyAdapter(private val itemList: List<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemLayoutBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = itemList[position]
        holder.bind(item)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemLayoutBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: String) {
            binding.itemText.text = item
        }
    }
}
```

#### Step 5: Set up your XML layout

Create an XML layout file for your RecyclerView (e.g., `activity_main.xml`). Make sure to enable data binding in the layout:

```xml
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <!-- RecyclerView -->
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            app:items="@{viewModel.itemList}"
            app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}" />
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

#### Step 6: Set up your Activity/Fragment

Update your Activity or Fragment to use collect on the Flow to observe changes in the ViewModel and update the UI:

```kotlin
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.databinding.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        // Set up RecyclerView and Adapter
        val adapter = MyAdapter(emptyList())
        binding.recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        // Observe changes in the ViewModel using Flow
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.itemList.collect { items ->
                adapter.submitList(items)
            }
        }

        // Load data from ViewModel
        viewModel.loadItems()
    }
}
```

#### Step 7: Run your application

Build and run your Android app. You should now see a RecyclerView populated with items from your ViewModel.

There are some simplifications here, but I believe it shows the idea quite well.

#### Update

You also need xml file for every item, I somehow missed that earlier. For example `item_layout.xml`.

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable_here">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

</layout>
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your replay, but i wanted to ask why you not created a layout xml (eg each_row.xml) for recyclerview . Also, it would be great if you could modify the code so that each item in the recyclerview show a text and image also from the drawable folder.

Comment: You're right, somehow I forgot about that xml file - I updated my answer. Speaking about setting the image: in the updated xml I added static image from drawable folder. You can also set the image dynamically. To achieve this, you need to modify the adapter so it gets itemList: List<Item>, where item will have two params: text and id of drawable from your file. Then, in the function bind() you need to add this code: binding.itemImage.setImageResource(item.image)